# How to Manage Client Specific Configuration

Tags: java, configuration, customization

For a product that is used by multiple clients where different clients ask for different customizations both user interface wise and functionality wise, how to accommodate those changes without getting the code cluttered with client specific code?

Are there any frameworks(for any programming language) that help with this?

To add more detail the UI is web based and written using JSP.

Comment: language agnostic for config? I don't think so.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the most difficult business requirement to manage different versions of same app, so do not expect open frameworks for that case, however each company involved develops its own system for sth like that.

As for business logic modifications, you would benefit for strong interfacing and **IoC** (such as **Spring**). You would override the services for your specific case and change the required methods, then inject into IoC the modified version of the service.

As for UI, it's more difficult because you've chosen JSP, which has little flexibility. When you'd be programming in Swing or GWT, than you could do UI modification same way - override needed UI classes, change them, inject modified versions. With JSP - propably there will be lot of modifications to .jsp files in your customized version.

Now the change modification/bug fixing - there is fully usage of version controll system. Of course, your customer-specific versions are branches, while main, standard version is trunk. Bug fixes are made to trunk, then merged to customer-specific branches. With interfacing/overriding implementations most of the merges would be the easy way, however, with JSP, I would expect conflicts to be often...

Generally, code changes merge easier than anything XML-based.

Answer (score 2):

How about simple [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)?  Set up a realistic interface/base class and depending on some sort of configuration, instantiate either child class A or B, depending on the client.  It's hard to provide more detail for a language-agnostic question like this, but I think it's very realistic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How about UI elements?

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this problem, common in the Win32/.NET world, is to move client-specific "code" into resource files.  Many .NET projects (.NET has built-in support for this pattern through the [System.Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74sfy6d5.aspx) namespace) use this pattern for internationalization, by placing the UI strings into one file per language, and then loading UI strings from the appropriate file at runtime.

How does this pattern apply to a JSP application?  Well, here you can keep one resources file per client (or, instead of files, use a database), and load the user-specific customizations from the resources file whenever you serve a page.

Say for example that your biggest customer wants to have their logo overlaid on some part of each webpage in your site.  Your page could load the `CustomerLogo` property, and use that as the src attribute for the HTML image at that part of the page.  If you are serving the page to the important customer, you load the URL "/static/images/importantCustomerLogo.png," and otherwise you fall back to the default resources file, which specifies the URL "/static/images/logo.png."

This way, you can abstract out the code for loading properties into one or two Java files, and just use those properties throughout the website.  The only part of your codebase that is customer-specific will be the set of resources files, and those can be in a clean XML format that is easy to read and modify.  The upshot is that people who didn't develop the application in the first place can modify XML without having to read the code first, so you won't have to maintain the resources files - the sales department can do that job for you.

Answer (score 1):

GWT does this out of the box via a feature called [deferred binding](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html)

When compiling a GWT application the compiler actually generates different versions of the code targeted for each different browsers. this is done automatically out of the box with the GWT components taking care of the different browser gory details.

This feature can be expanded to product arbitrary compilations based on custom properties. here is a simplified example: assume you have different view definitions for a normal and a detailed view

```
public abstract class AbstractView { ....}
public abstract class NormalView extends AbstractView { ... }
public abstract class DetailedView extends AbstractView { ....}
```

you can create a module definition that will generate two different versions,  one using the `NormalView` class the other using the `DetailedView` (in your gwt.xml file)

```
<define-property name="customMode" values="normal,detailed" />

<replace-with class="com.example.NormalView">
  <when-type-is class="com.example.AbstractView" />
  <when-property-is name="customMode" value="normal" />
</replace-with>

<replace-with class="com.example.DetailedView">
  <when-type-is class="com.example.AbstractView" />
  <when-property-is name="customMode" value="detailed" />
</replace-with>
```

using

```
AbstractView view = GWT.create(AbstractView.class);
```

will provide the appropriate instance at runtime.

It's up to you to encapsulate your client specific code into specific classes, and to expose common interfaces for the different implementations.

You will also need to select the appropriate compiled version according to the client currently viewing (you can use jsp for this.)

---

*please don't take the code samples above as tested, there might be problems with the syntax, it is just intended to convey the general idea*

---

A JSP backend is an ideal hosting environment for a GWT app, you will be able to take advantage of the requestfactory mechanism for easy communication between client and server.

obviously there is a learning curve here, IMO the [official documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you may try to read OSGi related articles (or books)...This platform would give you a very pragmatic answer to your modularity issues.It's especially designed to be able to handle different modules living all together with dependencies and versioning.
As mentionned early in an answer , dependency injection through the OSGi Declarative Services is a very valuable alternative to Spring , with dynamic capabilities.. Deploying a bundle providing a service and your references will be updated automatically , dropping it and they will be refreshed too...
Have a look to this technology and ask some questions after ?
Regards
jerome